# Rails rspec issues (cannot load such file --b (LoadError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard, spork

I'm following Hartl's guide to Ruby on Rails, and I'm currently trying to set up "guard" and "spork" for automating "rspec" testing. When I try to run
    `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

I get the following errors:

```
/home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `require': cannot load such file -- b (LoadError)
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `block in requires='
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `map'
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:434:in `requires='
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:20:in `block in configure'
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `each'
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `configure'
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /home/throne/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

I looked at other solutions for people who had similar kinds of problems (things like reinstalling gems, using absolute paths and fixing do / end statements in the target file), but none of them seemed to even change the issue. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your Gemfile. Change 'selenium-webdriver' to '~> 2.35.1', reinstall bundle and everything has to be OK!

Answer (score 0):

I had same error when tried to run test with single dash in params (need to run with --rdb).

Answer (score 0):

This page came up when I was researching the same problem using the same tutorial.  After some added investigation, I discovered that I was typing only a single dash on the --drb option. With a single dash rspec enables debugging and tries to require the file 'b'.  Very different from connecting to a DRb server :-